# Why does delete method is not working in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The destroy method doesn't work but i get redirected to index page but record is not deleted.

[image]

HTML.erb link:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", posts_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'are you sure?'},:class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

Controller:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

Comment: Side note: use two spaces for indentation.

Comment: `link_to "Delete", post_path(@post)` or just `link_to "Delete", @post`   Using `method: :delete` relies on javascript (`jquery-ujs` be precise) .  If the request is being sent as GET (check the logs) then you need to check browser console for javascript errors. You can also use `button_to "Delete", @post` which creates a form and does not rely on javascript.

Comment: Can you post your server log, when you click that link. Also, it should be `post_path(@post)`

Comment: I guess you removed `jquery-ujs` (or `rails-ujs` if rails > 5) from your `application.js`. Can you check if that's there?
That's the thing which handles all the link clicking HTTP method stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posts_path` is the path to `index` action. Change `posts_path` to `post_path` in the delete link tag to route to `destroy` action.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'are you sure?'},:class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

Comment: tried out the code but it just refreshes in the same page and doesn't delete the record.

Comment: @NidheeshJp If you don't want page to refresh then, add `remote: true` to the `link_to`